# Python: Dictionary where key is tuple of unknown order

Tags: python

I am trying to find a way to create a dictionary so that I can map a list of values to an appropriate function.

For example, I have something that looks like:

```
function_map = {('Put','Put','Call','Call'): FunctionOne,
                 ('Put','Call','Combo'): FunctionTwo,
                 ('Call','Put'):FunctionThree,
                 ('Put','Combo'):FunctionFour}
```

What I'm struggling with is how to deal with can a lookup value that can be in any permutation of the key.

For example, I might try to do  `function_map[(Call, Put, Call, Put)]`, and I would want this to return `FunctionOne`.   Or `function_map[(Combo, Put)]` I would want `FunctionFour` returned.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Either change the original map or create an intermediary map where you e.g. sort the entries in the tuple.

Comment: As a stupid alternative you can initialize dicts where keys will be all possible permutations of given tuple, assign same function to each and join them: `dict.fromkeys(permutations(('Put', 'Put', 'Call', 'Call')), FunctionOne) | dict.fromkeys(permutations(('Put', 'Put', 'Combo')), FunctionTwo)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@The Thonnu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18746959/the-thonnu)'s [*answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73012555/10824407) is memory efficient but lookup complexity is fairly high. The simple alternative which I've mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73012415/10824407#comment128954069_73012415) comment is to map all possible permutations of every tuple to same function:

```py
from itertools import permutations

function_map = (
    dict.fromkeys(permutations(('Put', 'Put', 'Call', 'Call')), FunctionOne) |
    dict.fromkeys(permutations(('Put', 'Put', 'Combo')), FunctionTwo) |
    dict.fromkeys(permutations(('Call', 'Put')), FunctionThree) |
    dict.fromkeys(permutations(('Put','Combo')), FunctionFour)
)
function_map['Call', 'Put', 'Call', 'Put']()
```

This option takes more time to generate mapping *(around 10 times slower than regular `dict` initialization)* but it makes each lookup ***significantly*** faster *(at least 10 times faster than lookup with function, [benchmark code](https://tio.run/##nZPNb4MgGMbv/BVvvAiL6WWXpUlPS3pcl6W3ZSG0xUkqYBD7kWV/uwOrBk2/Vi6IPjz83seX4mgzrZ5fClPXqdEShOXGap2XIGShjYWCG1lZZoVWJULzSq3940JxmEG3Wu51uMoMD7/OdWXcMmdytWFTeNOKI5S2H6lkBfUMqnKaHwRu4PiV5XmcQD@/V7abyBQCiGS8QcuVPiN1hGPpWOGpe80FG18K@h3C63wnVM/@9LQRazvxWW75scRhfBiHhQTlNTMhSVgZSR7wa7BDI1f3fUaDVEIDH8s/WM4w@NCISw2hDU/BZ@dzwwcybVxTbWCbwA5cime6YuI6Upa4FfshUjh48eD4bSDww3BbGQU7FCzmLC9d67n9lComOaUwm0FM3WlCURqfHNq@t0JyYZs3hRHK4miZcVieOhWveGlhzUpOoqSVTk4TjvoKb/xu7PeWDq2YRc3d60A6hM4oIuQSx16bu0CGDf3w0Yum1z/0d2ZvZzC8IZ/Xwvi6C2hoeA3tZixjtkE@D9LU9R8))*.

So if you will continuously search for function in this mapping, my answer is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
import itertools as it

function_map = {('Put','Put','Call','Call'): FunctionOne,
                ('Put','Call','Combo'): FunctionTwo,
                ('Call','Put'): FunctionThree,
                ('Put','Combo'): FunctionFour}

def func_map(x):
    for k, v in function_map.items():
        if x in it.permutations(k):
            return v
    return False

func_map(('Combo', 'Put'))()
```

(Goes into FunctionFour)

Answer (score 1):

A solution to your provided example could be something like this:

```
from itertools import permutations

function_map = {1: FunctionOne,
                2: FunctionTwo,
                3: FunctionThree,
                4: FunctionFour}

permutations_map = {1: list(permutations(('Put', 'Put', 'Call', 'Call'))),
                    2: list(permutations(('Put', 'Call', 'Combo'))),
                    3: list(permutations(('Call', 'Put'))),
                    4: list(permutations(('Put', 'Combo')))}


def get_function(perm: tuple):
    for key, value in permutations_map.items():
        if perm in value:
            return function_map[key]


function_output = get_function(('Call', 'Put', 'Call', 'Put'))()
```

where `function_output` is the output of `FunctionOne`.

If you run this code very frequently, the accepted answer is suboptimal because it computes the permutations each time you call it (making it slower), while this is just a lookup.

Answer (score 0):

If the value of each dictionary key can be unordered, you can sort each tuple to ensure the order is consistent.

##### Example

```py
function_map = {
    ('Call', 'Call', 'Put', 'Put'): FunctionOne,
    ('Call', 'Combo', 'Put'): FunctionTwo,
    ('Call', 'Put'): FunctionThree,
    ('Combo', 'Put'): FunctionFour
}
```

In order to access the values of the dictionary, I recommend you to use `.get` instead of accessing via `[key]`. It avoids unexpected errors while trying to access not existing keys.

For your examples, you may call with the following statements:

```py
function_map.get(tuple(sorted(('Call', 'Put', 'Call', 'Put'))))
# output: <function __main__.FunctionOne>

function_map.get(tuple(sorted(('Combo', 'Put'))))
# output: <function __main__.FunctionFour>
```

The output while accessing not existing key

```py
function_map.get("not existing key")
#output: <None>

# If you need an other values while accessing not existing key
function_map.get("not existing key", "default value")
# output: 'default value'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution is to use .get(). It will solve your problem.

```
function_map.get(('Put','Combo'))
```

If you want to execute the function try:

```
function_map.get(('Put','Combo'))()
```