# Python / Pandas -> Map list of items of pattern X, in unknown quantity, to values Y

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a dataframe where each row represents a leg of a trade.  I'm trying to reduce these legs into 'structures', where the structure = a set frequency / combo of the legs.

Here is a value_counts for example:

```py
slice_b.groupby("MainID")["GenStructure"].value_counts()
```

```
    MainID  GenStructure
2       Call            1
        Put             1
        Straddle        1
4       Put             1
        Straddle        1
6       Call            1
        Put             1
        Straddle        1
10      Straddle        2
        Call            1
        Put             1
20      Call            1
        Put             1
        Straddle        1
21      Put             2
        Call            1
23      Put             4
        Call            2
24      Put             2
        Call            1
86      Call            2
        Put             2
87      Call            2
        Put             2
97      Call            2
        Put             2
98      Put             4
        Call            3
99      Put             4
        Call            2
100     Call            2
101     Call            4
        Put             4
102     Put             4
        Call            2
103     Call            2
108     Put             4
        Call            2
111     Call            2
        Put             2
114     Call            4
        Put             4
145     Call            2
        Put             2
```

For each "MainID", I am trying to figure what the structure is.  If I were to simply map it to a dictionary [(like I asked in this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73012415/python-dictionary-where-key-is-tuple-of-unknown-order/73012600#73012600), I could use:

```py
structure_fx_map = {
    ("Call", "Call", "Put", "Put"): "RR",
    ("Call", "Put", "Straddle"): "Strg",
    ("Call", "Call", "Put"): "CallStruct",
    ("Put", "Put", "Call"): "PutStruct",
}
```

However, as you can see in the value_counts(), each MainID can have:

1. Multiple counts of the same structure
2. Sometimes there is a 'leftover' leg or two, which is the result of poor data.

My goal is to end up with something that looks like:

| MainID | Struct | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 'Strg' | 1 |
| 4 | 'Put' | 1 |
| 4 | 'Straddle' | 1 |
| 6 | 'Strg' | 1 |
| 10 | 'Strg' | 1 |
| 10 | 'Straddle' | 1 |

and so on...

Any help is appreciated! I'm open to other ways of doing as well.

Answer (score 1):

With your initial dataframe (before groupby):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'MainID': [2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 23, 23, 24, 24, 86, 86, 87, 87, 97, 97, 98, 98, 99, 99, 100, 101, 101, 102, 102, 103, 108, 108, 111, 111, 114, 114, 145, 145], 'GenStructure': ['Call', 'Put', 'Straddle', 'Put', 'Straddle', 'Call', 'Put', 'Straddle', 'Straddle', 'Call', 'Put', 'Call', 'Put', 'Straddle', 'Put', 'Call', 'Put', 'Call', 'Put', 'Call', 'Call', 'Put', 'Call', 'Put', 'Call', 'Put', 'Put', 'Call', 'Put', 'Call', 'Call', 'Call', 'Put', 'Put', 'Call', 'Call', 'Put', 'Call', 'Call', 'Put', 'Call', 'Put', 'Call', 'Put']})
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
matches = (
    df.groupby("MainID")
    .agg(tuple)["GenStructure"]
    .apply(lambda x: structure_fx_map[x] if x in structure_fx_map.keys() else pd.NA)
    .dropna()
    .reset_index()
)

# Exclude matches MainID for initial dataframe
df = df.loc[~df["MainID"].isin(matches["MainID"]), :]

df = pd.concat([df, matches])
```

```py
print(df.groupby("MainID")["GenStructure"].value_counts())
# Output
MainID  GenStructure
2       Strg            1
4       Put             1
        Straddle        1
6       Strg            1
10      Call            1
        Put             1
        Straddle        1
20      Strg            1
21      Call            1
        Put             1
23      Call            1
        Put             1
24      Call            1
        Put             1
86      Call            1
        Put             1
87      Call            1
        Put             1
97      Call            1
        Put             1
98      Call            1
        Put             1
99      Call            1
        Put             1
100     Call            1
101     Call            1
        Put             1
102     Call            1
        Put             1
103     Call            1
108     Call            1
        Put             1
111     Call            1
        Put             1
114     Call            1
        Put             1
145     Call            1
        Put             1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I dont think thats correct though, although its close!  For example, looking at MainID=145.  From value_counts(), we can see its some permutation of [2x Call, 2x Put].  This should return as "RR", count =1.

Comment: It might work, but I use an input dataframe (`df`) different from yours (`slice_b`), which I failed to reconstruct properly (it's a bit long by hand...). Could you provide the output of `slice_b.to_dict(orient="list")` rather the value_counts, and I'll update my answer?